# How to figure out what drive a Java program is being run from

Tags: java

I am creating a program that backs up my Documents folder to a USB anytime I run the program I created on it. The general makeup of the code I have is as follows, using Apache FileUtils:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
File docs = new File("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents");
File usb = new File("F:\\Files");
try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(docs, usb);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'd assume that the computer won't automatically assign my USB as slot F:\, so how do I get the program to find out what USB drive slot it is on so I can change the *F:* to *directory+":\"* or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via another system property:

```
String userdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```